# How do I change the colors used in MS Word 2007 track changes?

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2007

I'm reviewing a document in MS Word 2007, and when I add comments, the bubble has red text on a slightly lighter red background. This is pretty hard to read.

The *Track Changes Options* dialog isn't of much help, I can change the background color for Comments, and it's slightly more readable. But I know that Word assigns a color to each user who reviews the document, I'd like to be able to change mine to a different one, and still have it work properly when I pass the document on to others.

MS help is useless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently you can't, see ["Change the way that markup is displayed"](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/Track-changes-while-you-edit-024158A3-7E62-4F05-8BB7-DC3ECF0295C4#__toc252789688). Microsoft says:

> you can't assign specific colors for changes made by different reviewers

Comment: Hrm, whenever the correct answer is "you can't" my first impulse is to downvote the answer (instead of the developer). But alas, ["don't shoot the messenger"](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ShootTheMessenger)...

Comment: No better even in the [latest version of Word](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/Advanced-Track-Changes-Options-46207970-9f4d-4a9b-9f84-5155a394dd1e) either.

Comment: This answer is a perfect example of the reason, people should always quote the relevant information in an source, in link in question no longer works and had to be updated by somebody other than the author.

Comment: @Ramhound: This quote **is** all of the relevant information from both the old and new links.

Comment: @harrymc - I know that.  The edit appeared in the queue, I was just making a point, which I realize will never be seen by most people who need to read it.

Comment: @Ramhound: Well, I saw it ;)

Comment: @harrymc - You are the 0.01% that does not need to read it though :$

Answer (score 7):

You just go to 'Change Tracking Options', and choose your color.
There isn't a large variety, but it's better than red.

> Insertions are marked in red with
>   underlining, deletions are marked in
>   red with strikethrough, while moved
>   text is marked in green with double
>   strikethrough and underlining. Word
>   also places a vertical line in the
>   margin next to any changed lines. The
>   vertical lines and other revision
>   marks may be printed.
>
> To view the
>   track changes default markup and
>   color:
>
> On the Review tab, in the Tracking group, click the bottom half of the
>   Track Changes tool and select Change
>   Tracking Options. The Track Changes
>   Options window opens.
>
> [image: Change Tracking Options image]
>
> [image: Options window]
>
> If you
>   prefer that all of your edits be in
>   one color, such as red, you can
>   uncheck the Track moves checkbox in
>   the Moves area so that the green
>   formatting is turned off and all of
>   your changes will be in red.
>
> Later you will see that
>   Word assigns a different color to each
>   reviewer of the document.

[From here (pdf link)](http://training.uit.tufts.edu/pdftips/reword07.pdf), on page 9. It's very useful!

Comment: Great answer! I review documents all the time, and I had no idea I could get rid of that ugly red!

Comment: That's only a viable option for single author documents.  For anything colaboratively edited knowing who made what change is important requiring the setting left at By author meaning someone will always get the red color.

Answer (score 0):

In Microsoft Word 2003 (!), go to Tools, Options and choose the Track Changes tab. In there you can change the colours of the various changes. Hope that helps.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! This duplicates another answer and adds no new content. Please don't post an answer unless you actually have something new to contribute.